# How to get Textblock to display information stored in online XML File

Tags: c#, xml, windows-phone-7

I already achieved to download the XML File via Webclient but I do not know how to get my textblock to display the content I want.

My Code so far:

```
      private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {        
       WebClient wc = new WebClient();
       wc.DownloadStringCompleted += HttpsCompleted;
       wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?               
       format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=de-DE"));
      }

      private void HttpsCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
        if (e.Error == null)
        {
            XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            Textblock.Text = 
        }
      }
```

What do I need to do with the Textblock to get it to display the "copyright" section in the xml file above?

Since I am totally new to C# and WP7 please give me very simple answers - thank you very much for your time and help.

Edit:
I wrote:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
            var test = from txt in xdoc.Descendants("image")
                       select new
                       {
                           Test = txt.Element("copyright").Value
                       };
            foreach (var wd in test)
                image1Textblock.Text = wd.Test.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is better to use:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
String copyright = xdoc.Document.Root.Element("image").Element("copyright").Value;
image1Textblock.Text = copyright;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Textblock.Text = = from txt in xdoc.Descendants("copyright")
      select txt.Value; //Use txt.Element("xxx").Value or txt.Attrubute("xxx").Value to extract your value
```

Comment: sorry but this does not work in my case.
I get: an implicit conversion from type "System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<string>" in "string" is not possible.

Comment: Yap. Sorry, use xdoc.Element("xxx").Element("yyy").Value.

Answer (score 0):

The information given here did the trick:

http://omegacoder.com/?p=254

Comment: Your answer appears to be a *stub*. Please provide [more substantive details](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/72002/141525) rather than just posting a link.

Comment: I wrote the answer in my top post